# How to force tooltip to show in multiple graphs in highcharts with Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, highcharts

I am using vue3-highcharts with Highcharts. I want to achieve something like this: https://codepen.io/lzl124631x/pen/KLEdby?editors=1010 but I'm not sure how to write those functions inside Vue 3 (like syntax-wise).

So far I have managed to synchronize x-Axis zooming, hovering, and showing the crosshairs. However I cannot get the tooltip to display in all the charts. Here is what I did to get the xAxis to zoom:

```
xAxis: {
  events: {
    afterSetExtremes: function (e) {
      if (e) {
         Highcharts.charts.forEach((chart) => {
           if (chart && chart.index !== e.chartId) {
              chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max);
           }
         })
      }
    }
  }
},
```

And to get the hovers and crosshairs to sync I did this:

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    point: {
      events: {
        mouseOver: function (e) {
          let series = e.target.series;
          let index = series.xData.indexOf(e.target.index);
          
          Highcharts.charts.forEach((chart) => {
            if (chart && chart.index !== e.chartId) {
              let event = chart.pointer.normalize(e)
              
              let data = chart.series[0].data[index];
              if (data) {
                data.setState('hover');
                chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, data);
                
                chart.tooltip.refresh(data); 
              }
            }
          })
        },
        
      }
    }
  }
},
```

In order to get the tooltip to show I tried:

```
chart.tooltip.refresh(data);
```

But this returns an error.

Edit: Solution in case anyone ever stumbles upon this:

```
chart.tooltip.refresh([data]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The official Highcharts Vue wrapper, unfortunately, doesn't support vue3.

Comment: How would you do it in Vue 2 without using Event Busses?

Comment: Or how would I achieve it using mitts? Highcharts is working but I just don't know how to display the tooltip. It would be incredibly helpful if you could tell me how to force display the tooltip while hovering somewhere else.

Comment: Or I could make my own tooltip, but I can't get the values to assign to an external variable. For some reason "this" refers to the chart rather than the code. So I can't even extract the category and y value to build my own tooltip. So if you could help with that, it would be really helpful.

Comment: I could also have the tooltip always be displaying, maybe you could help me figure that out?

Comment: @MyNameJeff Could you reproduce described tooltip issue on some online editor that I could work on?

Comment: Ofc! Here you go: https://codesandbox.io/s/silent-microservice-z5yo8?file=/src/components/data.js

Comment: You can force the tooltip refresh by using a tooltip.refresh() method. API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Tooltip#refresh. So in your case on mouseOver when you use setState and drawCrosshair methods put this piece of code: `chart.tooltip.refresh([data]);`. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-albattani-2oj2m

Comment: Oh wow I could have sworn I tried that, ig I must have forgotten the square brackets. Thanks for pointing it out, it was driving me crazy!